# onActivityResult in fragment not called - possibly 'mixed' with other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39267399/5426412) solution and few others but seems like I missed something, and I can't found it.

In `Fragment A`, when user clicked a button, they will choose a place in map.

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
try {
     startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After choose the place, still in the same fragment, the address will be in an EditText.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("checkCall", "here");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // get the address
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), data);
                String address = String.format("Place: %s", place.getAddress());
                Log.d("address", address);
                editTextBizAddress.setText(address);
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                dialog("Error in getting the address");
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

So, in my parent activity - `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1001:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String tab = data.getExtras().getString("tab");
                if (tab.equals("profile")) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                }
                tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                        View focus = getCurrentFocus();
                        if (focus != null) {
                            hiddenKeyboard(focus);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        View focus = getCurrentFocus();
                        if (focus != null) {
                            hiddenKeyboard(focus);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}
```

I only managed to make it works only once. But after that, it doesn't work anymore. Though I have no idea how it can works once.

Is it because of the `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity`? Is it possible to get mixed up when other fragment also use `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity`?

**EDIT**:
I have changed the `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity` since the `requestCode` have different values, but still the same - `onActivityResult` in fragment not called.

Comment: Have you checked the google sample : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlacePicker/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placepicker/PlacePickerFragment.java

Comment: @MavyaSoni checked just now.. and no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the problem is about

```
super.onActivityResult...
```

in both activity and fragment.

Comment this line in activity. If it doesn't work - try opposite (remove it from fragment ant uncomment in activity)

Comment: try:  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in activity before switch

Comment: it works now. thank you! mind to explain a little bit?

Comment: By the way. If you find my answer a solution to your problem don't be shy to mark is as a correct answer ))

Answer (score 1):

For fragment to have a shot at receiving callback for **onActivityResult**, your **activity** must implement `onActivityResult()` and should have a call to `super` too.

For further explanations you can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment) answer.